# Scala regex and parentheses

Tags: regex, scala

I have the following string:

```
tagged.big) AND tagged.medium
```

I need to extract everything from this string that starts from tagged. and ends with one or more whitespaces or `)`

This is my current regex pattern:

```
tagged\.[\),\S]+
```

From the example string I expect:

```
tagged.big
tagged.medium
```

but right now it returns:

```
tagged.big)
tagged.medium
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/LrSZe7/2

Check it out this pattern, if it works, i can explain.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need!

Comment: I found that `tagged.big1` returns `tagged.big` but should also return `tagged.big1`.. and the same for `tagged.big2` Could you please check it?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/LrSZe7/4

Added .big1 (you can see it at the end of the list) and returns it without problem, re-check in your source program if it works.

Comment: thanks, works good right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex you use `tagged\.[\),\S]+` which contains a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with `)`, comma and `\S` which matches not a whitespace character. The `\S` also matches a comma and `)` so that could be shortened to just `\S+`. But that would match too much.

To match your values, you could for exampe use a [word character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` or add to the character class what you would allow to match:

`tagged\.\w+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQB0iQ/1)

That will match

- `tagged\.` Match tagged.
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gWCoNg/1)

Answer (score 1):

Final pattern : [**tagged.[^\W\s]+**](https://regex101.com/r/LrSZe7/5/) (You can see a further explanation on the site)

So it follows:

- 'tagged.' : matches any string with start with **tagged.**
- [^ ]: this matches a single character which is **NOT** presented on the set.
- [^\W\s] : matches a single character which is not a non-word or whitespace
- **+** : quantifier greedy, matches one or unlimited times the set.

Comment: `[$]` matches a `$` char, not an end of the string. `.` that is not escaped matches any char, not just a dot.